# Mysql error when select like

Tags: mysql, jdbc

pls help to solve below mentioned error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r.Username LIKE '%usernameanswer%' and  r.Createtime > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND

**Code**

```
public List <CorrekctanswerModel> answerlist(String usernameanswer) throws Exception {
       log.info("daomimpl" + usernameanswer);
    List<CorrekctanswerModel> answerarray = new ArrayList<CorrekctanswerModel>();

    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String sql = " select s.NAME as Subject, d.value as variant, r.Username, r.UserAnswer, r.Correctanswer, r.Createtime from resultlog r  " +

                 " inner join test_table t on t.ID = r.QuestionId " +

                 " inner join subject s on s.ID= t.SUBJECT " +

                 " inner join dictionary d on d.ID = t.Variant" +

                 "where r.Username LIKE '%usernameanswer%' and  r.Createtime > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND " ;

    try {

        c = DbHelper.getConnection();

        if (c != null) {

            ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();



            while (rs.next()) {

                CorrekctanswerModel rep = new CorrekctanswerModel();
                rep.setSubject(rs.getString("Subject"));
                rep.setVariant(rs.getString("variant"));
                rep.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                rep.setUseranswer(rs.getString("UserAnswer"));
                rep.setCorrekctanswer(rs.getString("Correctanswer"));
                rep.setCreatedate(rs.getDate("Createtime"));


                  answerarray.add(rep);


            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    } finally {
        JdbcUtility.close(c, ps, rs);
    }

    return answerarray;
}
```

Comment: Please share the full SQL statement otherwise we might not be able to fully debug it for you.

Comment: i have add full code. in log as you see i get "usernameanswer". but i couldnot use in sql for like.

Comment: put a space before `where` like so: `" where r.Username LIKE '%usernameanswer%'  ... "`. However, what you really need is `" where r.Username LIKE '%" + usernameanswer + "%' and ..."`

Comment: thx zedfoxus, it worked, great job.

Comment: Instead of concatenating values into a query, which leaves you susceptible to SQL injection, you need to use a prepared statement instead and set the parameter value in code.

Comment: @IslamIsmayilov did you find the answer below helpful? If so, would you mind marking it as accepted to put closure to your question? If you didn't find it useful, feel free to wait for additional answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add this as an answer in case someone stumbles upon this question...

In your code, SQL is generated with these lines:

```
String sql = " select <fields> from resultlog r  " +
             " inner join test_table t on t.ID = r.QuestionId " +
             " inner join subject s on s.ID= t.SUBJECT " +
             " inner join dictionary d on d.ID = t.Variant" +
             "where r.Username LIKE '%usernameanswer%' and ... " ;
```

There should be a white space before `where` OR a white space after `t.Variant`. In its current form, the query will do this:

```
... inner join dictionary d on d.ID = t.Variantwhere r.Username ...
```

Adding a space before `where` like so:

```
String sql = " select <fields> from resultlog r  " +
             " inner join test_table t on t.ID = r.QuestionId " +
             " inner join subject s on s.ID= t.SUBJECT " +
             " inner join dictionary d on d.ID = t.Variant" +
             " where r.Username LIKE '%usernameanswer%' and ... " ;
```

will result in your query written like this:

```
... inner join dictionary d on d.ID = t.Variant where r.Username ...
```

Also, it looks like `usernameanswer` is a variable. If it is, the `where` clause will look like this:

```
             " where r.Username LIKE '%" + usernameanswer + "%' and ... " ;
```